# Remove error class when success in jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin, and I've encountered a problem.

Whenever someone writes something in the field, and the field gets validated with no errors, the "error-message box" is still shown.

My question is, how can I remove this box?

This is my code:

**CSS:**

```
.register-box .field .has-error{
    border: 1px solid red !important;

}
.register-box .field .has-error.success {
    border:none !important;
}
.register-box .field .has-success{
    border: 1px solid #42CDA1 !important;
    background: #EEFBF7 !important;
    color: black !important;
    border-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.register-box .success > .error{
    border: 1px solid #42CDA1 !important;
}
.register-box .field .valid{
    border: 1px solid #42CDA1 !important;
}
.register-box .error{
    margin-left: 200px !important;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smooth: always;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    padding: 5px 7px;

}
```

**jQuery:**

```
  $('#myform').validate({

            debug: true,
            errorClass: "has-error",
            errorElement: "div",
            errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                        var name = $(element).attr("name");
                        error.appendTo($("#" + name + "_validate"));
                        $("#" + name + "_validate").addClass('error');
                    },


            /*errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo("#errorHolder");
            },*/
            success: function(label,element) {
                label.hide();
                //var parent = $('.success').parent().get(0); // This would be the <a>'s parent <li>.
                //$(parent).addClass('has-success');    
            },

            rules: {
                username: {
                     required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }

        },

            highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
                    $(element).addClass(errorClass);
                },

        messages: {
                firstname: "Enter your firstname",
                lastname: "Enter your lastname",
                username: {
                    required: "Enter a username",
                    minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
                    remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
                }
            },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='register-box'>
  <form  id="myform" class="register-form">
    <?php 
        if($checksuccess){ alert("success",$success); }
        if($checkerror){ alert("error",$error);
        }
    ?>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <div id="username_validate"></div>
      <input type="text" name="username"  value="" placeholder="Enter your desired username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      <div id="email_validate"></div>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter a valid e-mail address"/>
    </div>
    <button class="login-btn" data-disable-with="Signing In..." name="login" type="submit">Sign In</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Please see this jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5eb3pctr/**

As you can see, if you write something in the first input field, it gets validated (green border around input) - although the red "error-box" is visible.

Comment: At first glance, I noticed that you have addClass(errorClass) function, but you don't have removeClass(errorClass) when the validation is OK.

Comment: You don't need `success` or `highlight` as you're not doing anything different than the default.  By default, the plugin will apply and remove the error class and show/hide the label.  BTW-  the error class is removed with `unhighlight`, not `success`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `Success` you need to remove `error` class which you have added in your error container `div`

So your code will look like this;

```
success: function(label,element) {
    label.parent().removeClass('error');
    label.remove(); 
},
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/nk42db4f/)**